# Error invoking SecurityManager getting access to rmi server from webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, rmi

I have a webservice and works fine, actually I've tested it using its wsdl file from SoapUI.
But when I add code in order to get access to the rmi server wich contains all the funcionality that I need to use, everything goes bad

```
if(System.getSecurityManager()==null){
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/C:/Users/usuario/workspace/Interface/cliente.policy");
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
}

registro = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress,(new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
rmiServidor = (PeticionesInterface) (registro.lookup(serverName));
```

Debugging that code, at the moment that new SecurityManager is executed I get the following error

```
14:00:10,762 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014612: Operation ("read-children-names") failed - address: (undefined): java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.getContextClassLoader(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.SecurityActions$SetThreadContextClassLoaderAction$2$1.run(SecurityActions.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.SecurityActions$SetThreadContextClassLoaderAction$2$1.run(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.SecurityActions$SetThreadContextClassLoaderAction$2.setThreadContextClassLoader(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.SecurityActions.setThreadContextClassLoader(SecurityActions.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:383)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.getDeploymentNames(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:843)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.access$3300(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$ScanContext.<init>(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1177)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$ScanContext.<init>(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1173)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$DeploymentScanRunnable.run(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

I have security files for server and client.
This file on client

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "resolve,connect,listen,accept";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "usePolicy"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "*","read";
};
```

this file on server

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "resolve,connect,listen,accept";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
};
```

I know that both .policy files are not correct, but I've been adding permission as I obteined errors.

I've tried to use RMISecurityManager as well but I've got the same behaviour.

I don't know how to solve this error, anybody could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run both the client and server with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` and you will see exactly what is going on. Almost certainly your .policy file isn't being loaded.

Comment: Do you have below line in your policy file? grant {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
}; If you cannot grant permission on all ports, at least it should be enabled for required port ranges

Comment: I've added -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to the VM Parameters Tab in server project and I've obtained a list of messages (in red) wich show that the server side works correctly, however I have not could do the same thing at the dynamic web project because there is not an Arguments Tab at the Run/Debug Settings.

Comment: Can't help you until you solve that but I'm confident the policy file isn't being loaded. Double-check whatever does that.

Comment: You're absolutely right @EJP, the client wasn't loading the policy file. I've modified each and every java.policy in my system, so I suppose that it was a problem in the JBoss configuration.
Thank you for your help.